# Pandas extracting substring

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a column containing `dates`, which could look like `2017-10-12`. I want to create a new column containing the `day`, which in my case would be the number between the two `-`'s. I've tried various `.str.extract()` queries, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
df['days'] = df['dates'].str.extract('(-*)')
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second list by `str[1]`:

```
df['days'] = df['dates'].str.split('-').str[1]
```

Or [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format parameter + [`dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['days'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y-%d-%m').dt.day
```